# How to move the text in a footer over slightly

Tags: css, padding, margin, footer

I have a footer and I want all the text in it to move over to the left slightly so it looks a little more centered.  If I add a margin or change the padding them will alter all the 's and I don't want to do that.  I just want to move the text (links) as a whole over a little.

```css
.footer {
  background: #3E3D3D;
  padding: 0.625rem 0.75rem;
}

.footer_list {
  /*ul*/
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer_lists {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 1rem;
}

.footer_lists a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.footer_lists a:hover,
.footer_lists a:active {
  color: silver;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <ul class="footer_list">
    <li class="footer_lists"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="footer_lists"><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="footer_lists"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `<ul>` tag, by default, `padding-inline-start` CSS attribute value is set as `40px`. So you need to reset this value.

```css
.footer {
  background: #3E3D3D;
  padding: 0.625rem 0.75rem;
}

.footer_list {
  /*ul*/
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.footer_lists {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 1rem;
}

.footer_lists a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.footer_lists a:hover,
.footer_lists a:active {
  color: silver;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <ul class="footer_list">
    <li class="footer_lists"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="footer_lists"><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="footer_lists"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: Interesting, so how exactly does that work?  Seems to have centered it better.

Comment: So due to that default padding vaue, the ul width is `ul content width + 40px`. And that width is centered on the footer. So always, it's aligned 20px right on center.

Comment: Why is that the default value?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp will help you.